# How can I import data from Amazon RDS (MySQL) and render it on my S3 static website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I have a static website hosted on s3, having only one account field. On submitting this form, the Amazon RDS (MySQL) database should be queried (with 'account' as key) and some fields should be returned and displayed on the website.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> some fields should be returned and displayed on the website

this part separates static web sites from the dynamic ones. You can't do that with AWS S3, it doesn't support server side scripting.

You may try [aws lightsail](http://%20https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/) which supports your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a "compute" component that can appropriate query the database.

You could do this by making a REST call to API Gateway, which can trigger an AWS Lambda function. This function can run code that you provide. The code could query the database and return the information. Then, JavaScript code within your web page could render the returned content.

It's a bit complicated if you've never done this type of thing before. There are lots of examples online, such as: [How to Build a Serverless Web Application with AWS Lambda, Amazon API Gateway, Amazon S3, Amazon DynamoDB, and Amazon Cognito | AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/)